# Can the "Path" element be hidden once the final criteria has been met?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, page-layout, leads, pathassistant

I'm wondering if its possible to turn off or hide the "Path" across the top when the final criteria is met. Then have a new path show up in its place.

Currently the only way I can think about getting it to function like that is by creating a new page layout that will be activated once the "Path" is completed, but I want to avoid making another page layout as I have enough already.

[image: Hide The Path]

So once "Converted" is selected can I hide the Path or substitute it for a new path with different values?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this by using a Workflow Rule or Process that fires upon completion of the first Path. Let that automation convert the Record Type of the Lead to another record type, and update the Stage to the first stage in the lead process assigned to that new record type.

The Paths that you've configured for those record types in Path Setup would then be shown based on the record state.

The Path component uses Paths that are built in Setup (it's not a generic visual component for any picklist field), so you can't simply point multiple Path components at different picklists and use component visibility to surface them. However, if all you want to do is *hide* the Path at a particular stage, you can use the Component Visibility filter in Lightning App Builder.